# Strange behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

I've (had to :) ) became a C++ developer a few weeks ago (I had some experiences before but not too much, I was more in Java), trying to learn everything which counts and to develop as efficient as I can. So excuse if my question is totally dumb. I have a problem with a simple example template class:

```
template<typename T>
class SameCounter {
private:
    map<T,int> counted;
public:
    SameCounter(list<T> setup) {
        for(list<T>::iterator it = setup.begin(); it != setup.end(); it++) {
            counted[*it]++;
        }
    }
    map<T,int>::const_iterator& begin() { // line 25
        return counted.begin();
    }
    map<T,int>::const_iterator& end() {
        return counted.end();
    }
};

...
// using the class
Reader rdr;
rdr.Read();
SameCounter<char> sc(rdr.GetData());
```

I get some error when I'm compiling it:

```
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   d:\learn_cpp\examples\gyakorlas_1.cpp   25
Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'  d:\learn_cpp\examples\gyakorlas_vizsga\gyakorlas_1.cpp  25

(both of them twice)
```

I don't have a clue for it, something is wrong maybe with the templating I assume, because if I create the SameCounter as a normal class it is totally ok. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You'll need a `typename` before that `lsit<T>::iterator` and likewise for the map's const iterator.

Comment: A bit difficult to answer without knowing what line 25 is (where the error occurs).  But in general what these two errors are saying is A, you are trying to define a variable without a type definition and B you forgot to parse something OR that you are attempting to define a function as a reference (you return &val the function if you want to assign it as a pointer use the *)

Comment: "strange behavior" is probably the worst title you could choose. Only a few questions are really dumb, this doesn't look like it is, but it's not a well written one.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for it. I forgot a tiny "problem" occurs with templates when I want to refer on inner types. As answered below. Thanks for all.

Comment: For future reference, when writing the code excerpt, it's a good idea to mark the lines mentioned in the error message (e.g. with a comment like `//line 25 here`.

Comment: Unrelated: You probably don't want to take the list by value, and you probably don't want to use a `std::list` either (it's a linked list, not what they call "list" in Java; you probably want `std::vector`).

Comment: of course I wanted to use a linkedlist here, but yeah, i did not have to pass it by value to be more efficient

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should help you:

```
typename map<T,int>::const_iterator& begin() {
    return counted.begin();
}
typename map<T,int>::const_iterator& end() {
    return counted.end();
}
```

C++ templates are tricky. T is a template parameter, and `map<T, int>::const_iterator` could possibly mean different things (type names, but also - say - static members...) depending on what T you pass.

That's why in templates sometimes you need to make your intention clear and indicate that you actually mean "`const_iterator` is a type and I want a reference to it". The keyword 'typename' allows for that.

See: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

---

To make your code simpler and <s>avoid</s> reduce the need for `typename`, you could start with:

```
private:
    typedef std::map<T, int> MapType;
    MapType counted;
```

and then just go with

```
typename MapType::const_iterator &begin() {
```

Unfortunately this `typename` still needs to be here, you'd need further `typedef typename` for each dependent type to remove it from further declarations (see @**rhalbersma**'s answer).

---

Following @**rhalbersma**'s comment, let me also emphasise that **you should return these iterators by-value**. Returning references to temporaries causes undefined behaviour because the object gets out of scope and you end up with a "dangling reference".

So make it:

```
typename MapType::const_iterator begin() {
```

Comment: Geeez, thanks, I am totally dumb. You were right, I forgot that for templates the :: operator means generally that I refer on a static member and not a typename. Of course. Thank you again.

Comment: I've [compiled the code](http://ideone.com/0SDnvN) and you're going to need another `typename` in `list<T>::iterator` in the ctor. Go with the typedef pattern, it simplifies things a lot (and it's commonly used in the standard library - each standard template has plenty of typedefs for its "dependent" types.)

Comment: BTW newer compilers tend to bless you with errors like `error: need 'typename' before 'std::map<T, int>::const_iterator' because 'std::map<T, int>' is a dependent scope` (GCC).

Comment: @n3whous3: I'd hardly call you dumb for not being aware of this obscure C++ idiosyncrasy.  Even though it's my favorite language, I recognize a wart when I see one.

Comment: @Kos Why are you returning the iterators by reference instead of by value?

Comment: @rhalbersma Sorry, I paid attention to the OP's problem and didn't review the code as a whole. (EDIT: mentioned this issue)

Comment: Yeah, it gives totally irrelevant error messages sometimes, but I like it too. Even more, the most flexible language which I worked with.
@Kos: yeah, but strangely, that part of the code, when I iterate with that iterator, the VS compiler did not throw an error. Nonetheless, I wrote typename there also to be accurate.

Comment: @rhalbersma
I was the one who declared the reference return, that was not really ok of course :) At least this code had some problems afterwards.

Comment: @Kos While you're at it: also mark `begin() const` since it is returning a const_iterator ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I was not aware of strict my code as much as possible, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've annoted your class below. Several points are worth mentioning:

```
  template<typename T>
  class SameCounter 
  {
  private:
     typedef map<T,int> MapType; // typedef here to keep specific container in a single place
     typedef typename MapType::const_iterator const_iterator; // to avoid retyping "typename"
     typedef typename MapType::iterator iterator; // to avoid retyping typename
     MapType counted;
  public:
     SameCounter(list<T> setup) {
        // auto here to avoid complicated expression
         for(auto it = setup.begin(); it != setup.end(); it++) {
             counted[*it]++;
         }
     }

    // by value instead of by reference, mark as const member
    const_iterator begin() const {
        return counted.begin();
    }

    // by value instead of by reference, mark as const member
    const_iterator end() const {
        return counted.end();
    }

    // probably best to also forward cbegin()/cend() and non-const begin() / end()
 };
```

- **inner typedefs** come in handy if you ever want to change from `map` to another container (`unorderd_map` e.g.) and they avoid repeated typing of `typename` for nested typedefs.
- **auto** (C++11 keyword) can limit typing complicated iterator types
- **return by value** for iterators is the idiomatic way
- **const-correctness** of begin()/end()
- **overload** begin() / end() for non-const iterators and also provide cbegin()/cend()

In general it's best to use the same interface (constness, return value) as the function you are wrapping (map's begin()/end() in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, I got into C++11 also, I like the new features, but as I use VS2010, I lacks of some features.

Comment: I'm getting some weird HTML bugs with balancing < and > so that the code doesn't layout properly

Comment: @rhalbersma That's because your code block followed a list element directly, so the indentation was interpreted differently by Markdown. You could have added "Code:" before it and it would work as usual.